# How to check if two identical array exist in a single two-dimensional array? [Swift]

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm, multidimensional-array

if I have a two-dimensional array like this:  [[1,2,3], [3,2,1], [4,9,3]], I want to be able to find out that there are two identical arrays inside this array, which are [1,2,3] and [3,2,1]. How can I achieve this?

Thank you for all your answers, I was focusing on the leetCode threeSum problem so I didn't leave any comment. But since I am a programming noobie, my answer exceeded the time limit.. so I actually wanted to find the duplicated arrays and remove all the duplicates and leave only one unique array in the multi-dimensional array. I have added some extra code based on @Oleg's answer, and thought I would put my function here :

```
func removeDuplicates(_ nums: inout [[Int]] ) -> [[Int]]{
    let sorted = nums.map{$0.sorted()}
    var indexs = [Int]()

    for (pos,item) in sorted.enumerated() {
        for i in pos+1..<sorted.count {
            if item == sorted[i] {
                if nums.indices.contains(i){
                    indexs.append(i)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    indexs = Array(Set<Int>(indexs))
    indexs = indexs.sorted(by: {$0 > $1})

    for index in indexs{
        nums.remove(at: index)
    }

    return nums
}
```

Comment: I am sure you tried *something.* Don't be shy – show your attempt! (So that it does not look like a "give me the code" question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution is quite simple and easy to understand.

```
let input =  [[1,2,3], [3,2,1], [4,9,3]]
```

First let sort all elements of the nested arrays. (It gives us a bit more efficiency.)

```
let sorted = input.map{$0.sorted()}
```

Than we should compare each elements.

```
for (pos,item) in sorted.enumerated() {
    for i in pos+1..<sorted.count {
        if item == sorted[i] {
            print(input[pos])
            print(input[i])
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple and easy brute force approach that comes to my mind is:

1. Iterate over each row and sort its values. So 1,2,3 will become 123 and 3,2,1 will also become 1,2,3.
2. Now store it in a key value pair i.e maps. So your key will be 123 and it will map to array 1,2,3 or 3,2,1.

Note:- Your key is all the sorted elements combined together as string without commas.

This way you will know that how may pairs of arrays are there inside a 2d array are identical.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very efficient algorithm using permutation hashing method.

1) preprocess the 2-dim array so that all elements are non-negative. (by subtracting the smallest element from all elements)

2) with each sub-array A:
compute hash[A] = sum(base^A[i] | with all indexes i of sub-array A). Choose base to be a very large prime (1e9+7 for example). You can just ignore the integer-overflow problem when computing, because we use only additions and multiplications here.

3) now you have array "hash" of each sub-array. If the array has 2 identical sub-arrays, then they must have the same hash codes. Find all pairs of sub-arrays having equal hash codes(using hash again, or sorting, ... whatever).

4) For each pair, check again if these sub-arrays actually match (sort and compare, ... whatever). Return true if you can find 2 sub-arrays that actually match, false otherwise.

Practically, this method runs extremely fast even though it is very slow theoretically. This is because of the hashing step will prune most of search space, and this hash function is super strong. I am sure 99.99% that if exist, the pair of corresponding sub-arrays having the same hash codes will actually match.